# Ionic page does not exist but shows in error

Tags: ionic3

I had a page in my ionic project but when I removed it, it still shows an error even though I have removed its dependencies. Is there any command where we can clean this issue?

Comment: Try to delete the generated files (e.g. node_modules) .. then press (file -> invalidate cache and restart) and build it again.

Answer (score 0):

remove `www` folder. That folder contains your proyect compiled. After that,try to use `cordova clean` and`cordova build` in this order.

Answer (score 0):

> Try to delete the generated files (e.g. node_modules) .. then press (file -> invalidate cache and restart) and build it again.

This is false as node modules has nothing to do with your generated pages.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55026836/7271827) is correct